# Swift 4 : Adding UIView into the array programmatically with for loop

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift4

I'm using `scrollView` paging and I want to add `UIView`s into the `scrollView` programmatically with for loop. But I guess I'm missing something.

Here is my code :

```
func createSlide() ->[Slide]{
    for i in 0..<datas.count{
        slideAll?.append(Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ViewTest", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! Slide)

        slideAll![i].testLabel.text = datas[i]
    }

    return slideAll!

}
```

Is this possible that I can add `UIView` like that? If I can, how can I fix this code piece?

Edit :

I realized that I initialize the slideAll with no value on the top like that :

```
var slideAll:[Slide]?
```

How can I initialize this correctly? Should I initialize this on the function?

Comment: has `slideAll` initiated anywhere?

Comment: yeah, I'm adding this function for subviewing the uiscrollview.

Comment: Please please please - never show _pictures_ of code. Show _code_. Provide, minimally, _all_ the code needed to reproduce the issue. In this case, you hadn't even told us that there _was_ such a thing as `slideAll` or how it was declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this line:

```
var slideAll:[Slide]?
```

say this:

```
var slideAll = [Slide]()
```

Then remove the Optional unwrap notations from your references to `slideAll` in the rest of the code.

Answer (score 4):

`for i in 0...datas.count` will loop to the last slot array+1, then it will yell error because at that index there's no value, you should use `for i in 0..<datas.count` or `for slide in datas` instead

Comment: I tried what you said, but it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `datas` is initialized.

use for-loop as below:

`for text in datas {
// DO SOMETHING
}`

And I hope, you are subview-ing the views on uiscrollview somewhere in the code and it is not mentioned in the above question?

Comment: yes, I am adding the subview with another function. it works without loop and adding the views one by one. but I want to do add more than one view. that's why I'm struggling with for loop.

Comment: Can you show me more code? So that I can figure out.